# slogin via httpwebrequest post & check login(cookies) for https

Tags: vb.net, cookies

i have a database i m trying to check it via httpwebrequest .

i am trying to make it imports logins from text file (filename1.txt)
filename1.txt :

> username:password
>
> username1:password1
>
> username3:password3

after the checking is done export text file (filename2.txt)

> username:password success
>
> username1:password1 Failed
>
> username3:password3 success

i can make 1 httpwebrequest but i cant make a miltuple

source

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1

    Dim stackoverflowcookie As New CookieContainer


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim postData As String = "https://www.site.com/login.php?username=" & username & "&password=" & password "&submit=Login"
        Dim bytes() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.website.com/usercp.php")
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = stackoverflowcookie
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "http://www.website.com/index.php"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)"
        postReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length
        Dim postStream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        postStream.Close()
        Dim postResponse As HttpWebResponse
        postResponse = postReq.GetResponse()
        stackoverflowcookie.Add(postResponse.Cookies)
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(postResponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim strSource As String = reader.ReadToEnd
        If strSource.Contains("Welcome back") Then
         // here should write the in the textfile2 username:pass => Live txt file for the live accounts
        Else
         // here should make write in the textfile2 username:pass => Dead or a text file for the dead accounts
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Question : how to make it loop with importing logins from text file & how i write the results & if i loop it i should make it with socks so how do i import socks from text file & using it

Comment: Have the httprequest in a for loop

Comment: if i do that with https i am gonna need to make it check with socks

Comment: Hi - can you show us the rest of the code please?

Comment: @TarynEast take a look at it now